# Windows 10 command line to enable/disable tablet mode

Tags: windows-10, windows-tabletpc, tablet-mode

As title, does anyone know how to toggle tablet mode akin to swiping in the right then clicking Tablet Mode button?

Comment: There isn't a "command" to switch to Tablet mode.  However, that doesn't mean, [Enable Tablet Mode on Windows 10 through Code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31865120/enable-tablet-mode-on-windows-10-through-code) it cannot be done with your own application.  Of course based on the lack of quality of that single answer, you are going to really understand programming, to acomplish what you want from a command prompt (which would have to call your application)

Answer (score 1):

In fact you need 3 registry keys:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\TabletMode = 0

(this will only currently disable tablet mode before the next switch prompt)

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\SignInMode = 1 (this will enable Desktop mode on Signin)

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\ConvertibleSlateModePromptPreference = 0 (this will prevent prompts and will preserve desktop mode)